# Is it possible to attack system through torrent usage?

Tags: p2p, torrent

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What can do a hacker with ip address?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/what-can-do-a-hacker-with-ip-address)

I am using the Torrent for Downloading the Music and other files.

I heard that using Torrent can give IPAddress information to the other user. How to prevent from those attacks?

Or Is it just a myth that using Torrent can lead to security violations?

Comment: Your communication partners know your IP. That's a core design feature of the internet, not an attack. You need some kind of proxy (TOR, VPN,...) to obscure your IP.

Comment: http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/19018/what-can-do-a-hacker-with-ip-address

Comment: I believe this question could be extended out to ignore the focus on IP address information and instead specifically concentrate on whether torrents are secure. I would like to answer with that focus in mind. I believe generally it's a myth (the content is more likely to contain security issues) however a torrent client will usually accept connections from others and the torrent software itself may therefore contain security issues such as buffer overflow problems or design flaws. Some aspects of the Torrent protocol have been used as a traffic amplification attack also.